# AntDesign validation Typography editable text

Tags: regex, reactjs, forms, validation, antd

I'm trying to validate when the user is typing in the Antd Design Text, so that it does not let him write other value than numbers and onchange does not return anything.

"antd": "^4.3.3",
"react": "^16.13.1"

```js
import React from "react";
import { Typography } from "antd";
const { Text } = Typography;

export default class Demo extends React.Component {
    state = {
        price: 0,
    };

    onChange = (price) => {
        let isValid= validatePriceRegex(price);
        console.log(isValid, "Price:", price);
        this.setState({ price});
    };

    handleChange = (e) => {
        // In this part, I want to validate the input when the user is typing the value
        console.log(e); // dont return anything
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Text
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                editable={{ onChange: this.onChange }}
            >
                {this.state.price.toString()}
            </Text>
        );
    }
}

const validatePriceRegex = (price) => {
    const regex = /^\$?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/;
    return price && regex.test(price);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you seems to have 2 handle on change function.  the `handleChange` and the `handleChange`

editable Text component only accepts `onChange` inside of the `editable` props, so you have to do in the same on change function

```
import React from "react";
import { Typography } from "antd";
const { Text } = Typography;

export default class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    price: 0
  };

  onChange = price => {
    let isValid = validatePriceRegex(price);
    console.log(isValid, "Price:", price);
    // you validate here
    if (isValid) {
      this.setState({ price });
    }
  };

  // handleChange = e => {
  //   // In this part, I want to validate the input when the user is typing the value
  //   console.log(e); // dont return anything
  // };

  render() {
    return (
      <Text editable={{ onChange: this.onChange }}>
        {this.state.price.toString()}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

const validatePriceRegex = price => {
  const regex = /^\$?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/;
  return price && regex.test(price);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, validate is functional, but I want the user to not be able to see or write a letter, just format money

Comment: I doubt you have control of the input when it's in editing mode. since it's controlled internally as an uncontrolled component. the onChange as the TextProp doesn't seem to be called, and only call onChange when you save the text. you can see the source code https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/typography/Base.tsx#L408.

Comment: from my prev exp, modifying input value base on validation (AKA escaping chars is not a trivial problem because react always sets the cursor to the end. it's a known issue. see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/955

Comment: Great, I understand, I hope this problem can be improved